# No "Remove additional files at destination" option in publish settings for WebDeploy

Tags: c#, azure, api, publish, webdeploy

I have been having an issue where some files have been sticking around on our AzureApp Service location for an api I have been publishing. The error I get is:

```
"System.ArgumentException: 'A route named 'X' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
Parameter name: name' "
```

I have read that there is a handy option in the "File Publish Options" called "Remove additional files at destination". However in my own settings, I only have one single option shown below.

[image: WebDeploySettings]

Does anyone know why I don't have the option?

Comment: You have a code problem not a file problem. Somewhere 8n your startup or controllers you have a duplicate route.

Comment: My code has not changed, it was publishing fine until it just suddenly started presenting this error after a publish.

Answer (score 1):

Click this button, it will show like below.

[image]

[image]

## Tips

1. If not useful to you, please import profile which you can download from azure portal. Then retry.
2. Or maybe it's a bug in your machine, you also can upgrade your vs2019 to check again.